# Edit rejected when trying to make code compile

Tags: discussion, edits

I was wondering why my edit was rejected, not that I have a problem with it but I'd want to know when I shouldn't try to edit a post so I don't waste my time and community's time!

This is the link to the edit : https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5306474

I tried to edit the question to make the code compile so the question would be easier to answer to.

Comment: Link to suggested edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5306474

Comment: @Oded Should I include this to the question? I didn't think about adding it -.-'

Comment: Well, yeah. It gives more context and may provide extra clues as for why it may have been rejected.

Comment: Wow, that edit is sneaky. It looks a lot like a code reformatting but it's not. It adds code and changes the context. Robo reviewers didn't catch it

Comment: @staticx Actually nobody rejected it.  If you look closely, everyone approved it but it was rejected by the Community moderator because someone with over 2k rep edited it before the edit was approved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever you "fix" the code that somebody wrote in a question, you run the risk of invalidating the whole question.  This is especially the case for questions like the one you've linked, where the OP is experiencing an error or exception.

The OP says that there is an exception, but it's not unheard of that the "exception" actually ends up being a compiler error.

It also could be the case that this is not he OP's real code, and fixing the problem makes that harder to realize for potential answers.

---

If you see a problem with an OP's code, then you should tell the OP about it in a comment.  [If that practice good enough for Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765346/convert-generic-list-to-string-list#comment38427211_24765346), then's good enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

Code issues with a Question should be left to be fixed by the OP. Any problems may be the cause of their issue and "correcting" it could:

- Invalidate the Question
- Make answers no longer relevant or inaccurate
- or otherwise render the Question pointless

Certainly suggest changes or request clarification in the comments but 99% of the time: don't touch the code content.

This is especially true for a young Question where the exact details have not yet all come to light and there may be a degree of ambiguity in exactly what the OP is asking.
For older Questions where the details and intent are clear, improvements are more acceptable as long as they do not alter the Question too much and are a clear benefit to the Question and its Answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at when and by whom it was rejected

> Community♦ reviewed this 44 mins ago: Reject

it was the same time that a 2k+ user edited the question by looking [at the review history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24765346/revisions) so his edit trumped your suggested edit which is why it was rejected by community.

However, yours probably would have very possibly been rejected because it seems to have changed a lot. You were trying to do the right thing but see [the answer by indivisible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265742/edit-rejected-when-trying-to-make-code-compile/265743#265743) about more on that.