# Code Block Edits: Single Character Updates to Compile Errors --New Feature Request!

Tags: feature-request, edits

[Quite a few users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits/253651?noredirect=1#comment301435_253651), including myself, have been frustrated in attempts to edit/correct SO code that doesn't even compile.  I understand [that bad code in questions is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265742/edit-rejected-when-trying-to-make-code-compile?rq=1) ... but when the accepted answer doesn't compile, that is not good.

The six character minimum (for users under 2k reputation) combined with overly rigorous reviewing of these 'small' edits, means that these errors stay on SO until the author of the post reads the comment and gets back to fix the code error.  *Maybe never !*

To resolve the problem I'm shooting for a change of policy to allow single character edits IN CODE BLOCK with an added feature where the editors must comment on the severity of the code error.

Reviewers could then decide whether the code block edit is worthwhile ... and the six character minimum would remain for sections outside of code block.

The vast majority of SO users have under 2k reputation and are putting the code they find to use ... and debugging the code. Code, that due to the way it's presented on SO, could not be checked by a compiler alone.

So it seems a shame to stifle that error checking / quality improvement of code where those errors really undermine what is at the heart of what SO ... community access to good code!

Comment: First one getting the code formatting correct is the OP themselves.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm talking about compile errors.

Comment: Don't fix compiler errors in OP's question or answer, even if they don't ask for it! Never!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ why not?  It helps quality of content on SO ...

Comment: _"It helps quality of content on SO "_ I don't think so!

Comment: "Fixing" questions can easily misrepresent the problems in the OP's code.  That's a really terrible thing to do.

Comment: @StephanLuis Frequently (at least in the JS queue) those syntax errors are exactly what's plaguing OP.

Comment: ok, ok, ok...  I realise there's some confusion as to where the edits I'm talking about take place... not in the question of course! where a person knows code isn't working, but in the answer where the code is supposed to work!

Comment: Absolutely agree!

Comment: Recently, I have found a minor but not unsignificant typo in a code snippet posted in an accepted answer (stackoverflow.com/a/8630293/3817004) but was not allowed to remove the spurious character. I didn't want to blame the OP by placing a comment but to correct the typo silently for the benefit of other readers. Therefore, I support the suggestion.

Answer (score 18):

Welcome to what could be described as ***the*** most frustrating unspoken "rule" about editing.

In general:

- Code edits **in a question** are discouraged, since the edit may introduce new bugs independent to what the OP is asking, or may resolve the OP's problem.
- Code edits **in an answer** are encouraged, but it is strongly advised to place a well-detailed edit summary to explain what you did and why, as this is still pretty contentious.

If you're going to edit an answer, you have to be ***extremely*** careful about how you go about it, since in many cases, it's better to let the answerer "be wrong" as it were and downvote instead.

This is where things get tricky - if the answer *overall* is correct but there's a typo here or there, I could get behind this sort of thing.  However, there's nothing in the system that is capable of identifying this sort of thing, and I'm loath to trust reviewers to be capable of accurately and reliably identifying this sort of scenario.

Comment: I've updated the question (feature-request) to state that this should only apply to answers.  Thanks.

Comment: My answer still stands; if you're editing an answer, you can do that and that's fine, but you should be as explicit as possible as to why you edited the answer and why.  I'm not *as* bothered about answer edits as most other people are.  I can deemphasize the question bit a little later.

Comment: That's the problem the answer edits are getting shot down.  What to mean by deemphasize the question later?

Comment: also that's why this is a feature request... the hope is have a new feature to handle 'correct' answers that don't compile.   It might be worth while looking through answer edits to see how many in code block are rejected by reviews.

Comment: "if the answer overall is correct but there's a typo here or there, I could get behind this sort of thing." --exactly my scenario.  "I'm loath to trust reviewers" --I agree-- only the poster who's being corrected should be able to approve an edit-- their name is on it, and it affects their reputation.

Comment: @johnywhy that's a great addition to the feature, having the poster approve the edit within a code block.

Comment: @Makoto Since posting this feature request I've come across Jon Galloway's dormant account that he closed 'because the moderators close or delete far too many of the useful questions'.   To guard against zealous reviewers has a great idea to allow the poster-- that's being corrected --approve or reject the 'small code block edit'.  This is definitely worthwhile, SO is loosing too much valuable input to do without.

Comment: @StephanLuis, i started a thread proposing just this yesterday. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316923/209942 The thread got a -60, and was shut down for being "off-topic--does not seek input". Objections included "This suggestion assumes that the poster knows the best for the community, which would most probably not the case." "The OP is the least significant user to decide whether an edit should be approved or not. The edit was most probably done because their lacking of knowledge." "In case the OP does not come back for a long time, the post will probably bear the issue for a longer time."

Comment: @StephanLuis Jon Galloway's message has absolutely nothing to do with editing content, or the 6-character requirement. Regardless, he has 30k reputation and is not subject to the 6 character requirement for edits.

Comment: @meagar I think JG's comment does represent a growing problem on SO, good content is overlooked (more ... it seems, actively repressed ... ) and I am recommending a feature that will at least improve the situation by removing typos and bad code to make answers more reliable.  (more on scores required below)

Comment: @johnywhy what was you post that was removed?

Comment: @johnywhy:  If you're going to insist on discussing that post, then you're going to want to take it to a chat room with you and Stephan.  I'm not much of a fan of this appearing in my inbox.

Comment: At @Makoto's request, i posted that delete thread here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103658/edit-moderation-by-poster  Strange Makoto said I will want to, when they really meant *they* want me to.

Comment: @StephanLuis i also posted in the chat room, my other post that got deleted "Remove 6-character Minimum on Suggested Edits" http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103658/edit-moderation-by-poster

Comment: @StephanLuis While we're on the topic, i added a link to the THIRD of my threads that was deleted yesterday (i had a good day). In all 3 cases, the threads were deleted from public view after someone posted an offensive, insulting post. The persons posting the insults were among those who deleted the post. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103658/edit-moderation-by-poster

Answer (score 0):

I **agree** with OP, but think micro-edits should be possible anywhere (i.e. not just inside code blocks) and with OP approval.

I sometimes find typos like `recieved` in otherwise perfectly good questions and answers.

I've seen a few code errors too, but not as many. Stuff like this:

```
$ This could be some code.  You don't have to know anything about code to see that it's improperly formatted markdown.
````

Nobody needs to have *2,000* reputation of knowledge in a subject to recognize these unrelated errors.

@Makoto said:

> Code edits in a question are discouraged, since the edit may introduce
>   new bugs independent to what the OP is asking, or may resolve the OP's
>   problem.

Sure, but changing more than six characters could solve the problem too, right?  OP's feature request is about the 2,000k reputation requirement.  Please address that in your arguments.

> Code edits in an answer are encouraged...

Yes, e x a c t l y. It's [frequently brought up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=downvoting%20new%20users) that downvoting new users is discouraging, but new user questions are often unclear or poorly-phrased.  (A little punctuation goes a long way).

Not to mention that these Q/As are archived and googled and visited over and over again, and used frequently for reference.  Those small errors *persist* if nobody with enough reputation can edit them.  In the worst case, major typos can inhibit proper search engine indexing, making that information harder to find.

> ...but it is strongly advised to
>   place a well-detailed edit summary to explain what you did and why, as
>   this is still pretty contentious.

...

> My answer still stands; if you're editing an answer, you can do that
>   and that's fine, but you should be as explicit as possible as to why
>   you edited the answer and why. I'm not as bothered about answer edits
>   as most other people are. I can deemphasize the question bit a little
>   later.

Whether edits are accompanied by a detailed summary is entirely unrelated to OP's feature request, which specifically addresses the 6 character minimum at less than 2000 reputation.

Tl;dr: Fixing small errors shouldn't require any field expertise.  All the "arguments" against OP's feature request are non-sequiturs, except for the one which actually *agrees* that edits to answers are encouraged.

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23329162/3006854), somebody wrote "in toher words".  I'd fix it but am not allowed.  Justify that, somebody.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9324559/3006854) has an error in the code.  Seems to be missing some `)`s.  Can't fix, won't fix.

Answer (score -6):

I think the <6-character edits may prove to be overwhelmingly typos and other mistakes, fixes of which the OP is quite qualified to understand and approve.

So i suggest the following revision of OP @StephanLuis request: allow <6-character edits, in code blocks only, and *empower the poster to approve/disapprove the edit.*

*ALSO empower 3 community reviewers to approve the edit*-- **BOTH** approvals would work. Thus, in cases where the poster fails to return to SO to approve the edit, others community reviewers would fill the gap.

Comment: Regarding your last two paragraphs, this is already how the site works. The poster already is "empowered" to approve/disapprove edits to their posts, and the community is also already able to review the edit. You haven't proposed any changes, except to allow trivial edits (fewer than 6 characters) to code blocks. Regarding that change: If you want to make edits involving fewer than 6 characters, use the site for a while, gain 2000 reputation, and unlock that ability. It already exists.

Comment: Regarding your last 2 sentences, the 2k requirement was already mentioned here (and elsewhere). You have provided any new information.

Comment: Yet you failed to actually *address* this information in any way. The fact is, you are proposing changes that would grant you privileges that you would otherwise earn though the normal course of time, which everybody else had to earn. You haven't provided any reasoning behind why you think this change is necessary.

Comment: The reason is as the OP states-- in code, a single character makes the difference between code that works and code that doesn't. Seems the prevailing view is that a single character isn't "important" enough to deserve review -- which in programming is completely false. Also, re my rep, i've got voted down yesterday over 60 points for making a *suggestion about the website.* Which has nothing to do with my contribution to programming topics. I've participated with good intentions on the site for years, never posting spam or anything abusive, but nowhere near 2k.

Comment: @meagar I have a meagre score of 333, although I spend a lot of time on SO and writing code ... I don't have the ambition to score 2,000 (which, by the way is mentioned in my post) ... but that 'scoring' seems to become the point of SO.  SO is becoming much less to do with code and more about 'this is how it is at SO, so if you want to contribute (and score) this is what you have to do'.  How sedentary in attitude is 'Welcome to THE most frustrating feature of SO' ...But, no just fix the problem!

Comment: @johnywhy votes on meta don't affect your reputation